# ASP.net Core y Swagger, EndPoint con doble funcionalidad

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Tengo un problema, estuve probando una manera de utilizar un endpoint para realizar 2 acciones diferentes, mis 2 acciones son buscar por ID y si no se ingresa ID que devuelva todos los elementos, pero no logro hacer que funcione, intente darle una sobrecarga al metodo en cuestion y swagger crashea. Tambien probe detectar el campo y dentro del mismo metodo, llamar al metodo2 para que realize GetAll en caso de estar vacio, pero swagger me dice que el campo es `required`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class MercaderiaController : ControllerBase
        {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
                public IActionResult GetMercaderiaByID(int id)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var mercaderia = service.GetMercaderiaByID(id);
                        var response = new ResponseBadRequest { Error = "No existe ID ingresados", CodigoError = 400 };
                        return (mercaderia != null) ? new JsonResult(mercaderia) { StatusCode = 200 } : new JsonResult(response) { StatusCode = 400 };
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(e.Message);
                    }
                }
         }
```

Comment: y cómo no va a ser requerido, si colocas `int id`, otra cosa sería que coloques `int? id` y se considera opcional :D Por cierto, ese mismo cambio debería estar dentro de tu `service.GetMercaderiaById`, aunque no le veo sentido lógico para ser sincero, pides un ID y devuelve todos si no hay uno ingresado, bueno, cosa de seguir los lineamientos del requisito. Saludos

Comment: Aunque le pase `int? id` me sigue pidiendo un campo.

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

1. Revisa que la lógica del código y del servicio sea entendible, mandas código pero tiene un comportamiento por defecto en caso sea null, el nombre del método podría cambiar.
2. Swagger siempre revisa los data attributes primero [HttpGet], [Route] y en base a ello genera la documentación en caso existan, de lo contrario toma lo que hay en los parámetros, por eso, así le pongas `int? id` en el parámetro, en el HttpGet sigue como id.

Código:

```
[HttpGet("{id?}")]
public IActionResult GetMercaderiaByID(int? id){
 ...
}
```

Comment: En tengo `[Route("api/[controller]")]` en este caso controller seria mercaderia, pero probe con lo que pasaste y no lo toma, en la parte del query retorna null si el ID no existe, de esa forma forma puedo generar el badrequest, el problema es que no puedo pasar el required atravez de swagger, segun lei hay un json que se llama openapi specifications y tengo que cambiar un campo de required a false, pero no lo puedo encontrar.

Comment: En ese caso, coloca más detalles, como tu código completo, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822